# Additional paragraph being created

Tags: html, css

When I try to run this piece of code, I see additional paragraphs are being inserted after each paragraph..How can I clear those paragraphs or why I see it?

```
<html>
    <style>
        /* The margin set from - top, right, bottom, left*/
        p {
            margin:.5cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
            text-decoration:underline;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:red;
        }


    </style>
    <body>
        <p>This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph<p>
        <p>This is the Second paragraph<p>
        <p>This is the Third paragraph<p>


    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvF85/

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your paragraphs properly

```
<html>
    <style>
        /* The margin set from - top, right, bottom, left*/
        p {
            margin:.5cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
            text-decoration:underline;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:red;
        }


    </style>
    <body>
        <p>This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph,This is the First paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the Second paragraph</p>
        <p>This is the Third paragraph</p>


    </body>
</html>
```

Almost all html tags start with **<>** and end with **< / >**